# Cant run function that is in .js file

Tags: javascript

I know I should be able to run this function

```
function fba(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
             console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
               console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
             });
            } else {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, {scope: 'id,name,gender,is_verified,timezone,picture.width(800)', return_scopes: true});
}
```

However because it is included in the footer like so

```
  <script src="./templates/main/user-theme/javascript/facebook.js"></script>
```

It seems the html part of the website can't get its head around `onClick="fba();"`.

```
     <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook" onClick="fba();">
        Continue with Facebook
      </button>
```

Error is  `fba is not defined`.

Comment: Please make sure your js file or fuction is added first, before the calling the function.

Comment: because your JS Is loaded later on, if you dont want to change the JS Structure then dont have tightly bound code, bind click event on the button in JS instead of using onClick

Comment: Try putting the SCRIPT tag on top and see if that makes any difference. It shouldn't. But, are you sure the file reference is correct? Add a `alert('I loaded!')` to the end of your facebook.js code just to make sure it arrives.

Comment: @ParthGhiya On the contrary, the html attribute onclick is not an early bind. The browser first checks that out upon clicking. But if you want JS to do it, it should be done from that very facebook.js script.

Comment: Just want to make sure you know you are working with a submit button

Comment: `onClick` should be `onclick`.

Comment: For those that think that case is the issue, http://jsbin.com/xezubor/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I fixed it by making the onclick function be called by the JS file based on the user clicking on the ID

Comment: Just want to make sure you understand that <button></button>, by default is a submit button. A regular button would be <button type='button'></button>

Comment: @RussellHarrower Since you got it working you should post your solution as an answer and accept it.